# Logic behind printing pyramid shape using nested for loops in Java

Tags: java, for-loop, nested

I have modified sample code around to get the output I was looking for, but I do not understand the logic behind the nested for-loops below. Can someone explain to me in detail what each loop is doing and why is are the loops constructed in this way?

```
public class Pyramid {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int size = 15;

        for (int i = 1; i <= size; i += 2) {

            for (int k = 0; k < (7 - i / 2); k++) { 
                System.out.print(" ");
            }

            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) { 
                System.out.print("*");
            }

            System.out.println();
        }
    }      
}

output (below):

       *
      ***
     *****
    *******
   *********
  ***********
 *************
***************
```

Comment: Fix your indentation and it will be much clearer to you! When drawing pyramid, you need to draw on every `i`-th line `0..(N-i)/2` spaces followed by `1..i` stars.

Comment: I have downvoted this question because there is no evidence of any research.  Please [edit] your question to include the research you have done and *precisely* where you are having difficulty.  If you can do this, I may retract my downvote.

Comment: Which part of the outer loop don't you understand?

Comment: There's a problem with the maintainability code, it says `int size = 15` at the top as if you can configure the size of the triangle by changing that number, but later it has the number `7` hard coded into it; this should be changed to `size / 2`.  Furthermore the `int size = 15` should be changed to something like `int rows = 8; int size = rows * 2 - 1;` so that you configure the triangle's size by the number of rows, and also know that `size` is always an odd number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nested for loops like that are used when you have pseudo code like this:

```
Do the following x times:
    Do the following y times:
        some stuff
    Do the following z times:
        some stuff
```

In your specific case, the size of the pyramid is dynamic and is stored in a variable called `size`. To print a pyramid, you have to print `size` times the following thing:

- Some whitespace and some `*`

How do you print that then? You calculate how many white spaces and `*` should there be and print them. Since the numbers of whitespaces and `*` are dynamic, you need a for loop to do this, instead of hardcoding them in.

Do you see the structure now?

The outer loop prints each layer of the pyramid. The first inner loop prints the white spaces and the second inner loop prints the `*`.